# Is there a dimension function that works for vectors, matrices and arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, vector

As we all know the function `dim` calculates the dimension of a multidemnsional array or matrix.

```
n = 2
A = matrix(rnorm(n^2),n,n)
dim(A)
```

Which yields the answer 2,2 as expected. Now the issue is often you don't know if an object will be a vector or a matrix or an array. `dim` only works on the latter two types. Of course one could write a function as follows

```
dimVorM = function(x) ifelse( is.vector(x), return(c(1,length(x))), dim(x) )
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: If it helps, there are `NROW` and `NCOL` functions that work on both matrices and vectors.

Comment: So I would call your function `DIM` for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write something like this, which would be analogous to `NROW` and `NCOL`.

```
DIM <- function(x) if(is.null(dim(x))) length(x) else dim(x)
```

I wouldn't return a length-2 vector if something only has one dimension. And don't use `ifelse` for control flow.

Comment: I'd do `DIM <- function(x) if(is.null(d <- dim(x))) length(x) else d` to eliminate one call to `dim()`. That would be completely equivalent to `NROW` and `NCOL`.

Comment: Well, you're trading off reading an attribute for an assignment, so efficiency-wise I don't think there's much to gain. Doig an assignment inside a logical test is squicky though.

Comment: I just copied the internal code of `NROW` and `NCOL`. This assignment inside a logical test etc is done all over the internal code of base R functions. But I agree that R moved away from the classic functional programming paradigms it was once based on, so I wouldn't use that myself in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `dim()` works for vectors. The function `dim()` extracts a "dim" attribute and returns its values. A vector doesn't have that attribute `dim`, so the function `dim()` rightfully returns `NULL`.

```
> x <- 1:10
> attr(x, "dim") <- c(2,5)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
> dim(x)
[1] 2 5
> attributes(x)
$dim
[1] 2 5

> dim(x) <- NULL
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> dim(x)
NULL
```

The `dim` attribute is a vector with one value for each dimension, indicating the number of elements in that dimension. Both `NROW` and `NCOL` are constructed in such a way that they consider a vector to be a column vector with 1 column and `n` rows, and the solution of Hong Ooi is consistent with this.

Also keep in mind that a table is something entirely different. That is not a vector but a one-dimensional array :

```
> y <- table(iris$Species)
> y

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        50         50         50 
> dim(y)
[1] 3
> class(y)
[1] "table"
```